# Debugging the error "Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent" in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a function `VanderPol()` which is supposed to give a vector output, but it doesn't seem to work. It is just three lines of code but I cannot seem to find the bug.

The function is

```
function [output] = VanderPol(y, i)
    output = [y(2,i); (1-y(1,i)^2)*y(2,i) -y(1,i)];
end
```

and it is called as

```
z = [1 2 3;
    4 5 6];
VanderPol(z,1)
```

I recieve an error message stating that `VanderPol(z,1)` is faulty, but no hint why. The exact error message is shown below. Can anyone spot the bug?

```
Error using vertcat
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.
```

Comment: Interesting, a small change of `output = [y(2,i); (1-y(1,i)^2)*y(2,i) -y(1,i)];` to `output = [y(2,i); ( (1-y(1,i)^2)*y(2,i) -y(1,i) ) ];` helped. However, my matlab gave the error msg: Error using vertcat, no idea why you dont get any ...

Comment: Great, thanks! It did? I updated my matlab software as of yesterday, it should be fine. I'll take another look at the error, I might have missed something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bit of an edge case: You can construct arrays in MATLAB by separating elements either by a comma `,` or a space . Thus, the following ways both work and give the same result:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1 2 3]
```

When building matrices, this works similarly, and rows are separated by a semicolon or a new line, i.e. we have the following equivalent possibilities:

```
A = [1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6]
B = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]
C = [1, 2, 3
     4, 5, 6]
D = [1 2 3
     4 5 6]
```

Now to your example: your array is the following:

```
[y(2,i); (1-y(1,i)^2)*y(2,i) -y(1,i)]
```

The first row contains one element `y(2,i)`. The second row, however, is interpreted as two elements: `(1-y(1,i)^2)*y(2,i)` and `-y(1,i)`, due to the space between these parts. I.e. MATLAB thinks you are using a space to separate two parts of an array like in `b` above. It interprets the input like the following:

```
[y(2,i); (1-y(1,i)^2)*y(2,i), -y(1,i)]
```

If you paste the code into MATLAB, you will thus get an error complaining that it is not possible to have an array with 1 element in the first and 2 elements in the second row:

```
>> [y(2,i); (1-y(1,i)^2)*y(2,i) -y(1,i)]
Error using vertcat
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.
```

To solve the problem you have to tell MATLAB that there is only one element in the second row, given by the subtraction `(1-y(1,i)^2)*y(2,i) -y(1,i)`. Here are some ways to do that:

```
output = [y(2,i); (1-y(1,i)^2)*y(2,i) - y(1,i)];    % spaces on both sides of -
output = [y(2,i); (1-y(1,i)^2)*y(2,i)-y(1,i)];      % no spaces around -
output = [y(2,i); ((1-y(1,i)^2)*y(2,i) -y(1,i))];   % parentheses around everything
```

Comment: Very nice answer. You know, I think this sums up all the bugs I have come across that I didn't have a idea of how to approach since I couldn't see it! I always had to go back and just rewrite the code, and magically it sometimes worked (sometimes not), although the error-free code looked the same as the good code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great to hear, it's a pleasure to help.